# Parallel execution of computationally expensive map

Tags: multithreading, scala, system.reactive, reactive-programming, rx-java

I am new to the ReactiveX library (I use its scala variant, RxScala).

I have an `Observable` that emits values at high rate. I would like to apply a function to all values of the `Observable` (`map`). The function, which I use in `map`, is computationally rather expensive.

Is there a way to have a thread pool for computing the `map` phase in parallel?

Comment: Show some sample code to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, there is a way to do this.

I would buffer the stream into chunks and distribute the load across cpus using `Schedulers.computation()` (which uses an `Executor` based on a thread pool with size equal to the number of available processors):

```
int chunkSize = 1000;
source
  .buffer(chunkSize)
  .flatMap(
    list -> 
      Observable
        .from(list)
        .map(expensive)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
 ...
```

If the `map` operation is sufficiently expensive you might be just as performant without `buffer`:

```
source
  .flatMap(
    x -> 
      Observable
        .just(x)
        .map(expensive)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
```